# initializing element constructor in 2 dimensional ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, initialization

```
public class Build_Cells extends Loop {
private List<List<Cell>> map = new ArrayList<List<Cell>>();
public Build_Cells(){
}
public Build_Cells( int height, int width , int cell_size ){
    int col = height / cell_size;
    int rows = width / cell_size;
    for( int y = 0; y < col ; y++){
        map.add(y, new ArrayList<Cell>(rows));
    }
}
```

};

In the last line of code: map.add(y, new ArrayList(rows));
I want it to run Cell's constructor Cell() for every element in the ArrayList (rows) - but how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You create the list of lists and all the lists in it. But not actual Cell objects. Try this:

```
for( int y = 0; y < col ; y++){
    List<Cell> colObj = new ArrayList<Cell>(rows);
    map.add(y, colObj);
    for( int x = 0; x < rows ; x++){
        colObj.add( new Cell() );
    }
}
```